# Correlation between three variables

Tags: correlation

If

1. A and B are correlated
2. A and C are correlated
3. B and C are not correlated
4. A is correlated with variables other than B

Is it accurate to say that C is correlated with A only when the change of A is not caused by the change of B?

Comment: Two words in your question make my brows raise: *"when"* and *"caused"*. All your previous assumptions are about correlation, not causation...

Answer (score 0):

Comment:

Not sure what the 4th condition means. As @Evargato comments, correlation does not imply causation.

Here are three samplea `a`, `b`, and `c`, each of size 100 (sampled in R), that appear to satisfy conditions 1, 2, and 3.

Can you please be more specific about what you're asking?

```
set.seed(2020)
x = rnorm(50, 100, 15)
y = rnorm(50, 100, 15)
z = rnorm(50, 100, 15)
a = c(x,y);  b = c(x,z);  c = c(z,y)
cor(a, b);  cor(a, c);  cor(b, c)
[1] 0.3811942
[1] 0.4737169
[1] -0.1004705

pairs(list(a,b,c))
```

[image]

Comment: I conducted an experiment where I changed Quantity B and saw how Quantity A changed accordingly, and there was another data set of quantity C. Quantities A and B were found to be strongly correlated, and Quantity C was found to be strongly correlated with A, but not with B. So, from this given information only, I wondered if it is accurate to say that Quantity C is strongly correlated with A, but only when the change of Quantity A is not a result of the change of Quantity B, because Quantity B has a weak correlation with Quantity C. If this is not correct, what is an appropriate conclusion?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'chages' in the various samples. Of course a change in a sample can change its sample mean, median, SD, and correlation with another sample. // Look at the formula for the sample correlation btw two samples, it has their SDs in the denominator. // The goal of your investigations is not clear to me.