# Correlation between several variables

Tags: correlation, modeling, multivariate-analysis

I had a [previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/493860/correlation-between-three-variables/493881#493881), but it was poorly written due to my lack of knowledge in statistics.

In an experiment I controlled $X_2$ and observed changes in $X_1$. $X_1$ and $X_2$ were found to be strongly correlated, and $X_3$ was found to be strongly correlated with $X_1$, but not with $X_2$.

Is it accurate to say that $X_3$ is strongly correlated with $X_1$, but only when the change of $X_1$ is not a result (this might sound like I'm bringing in causation here but I don't know how else I should describe my thought, sorry) of the change of $X_2$, because $X_2$ has a weak correlation with $X_3$. Or, I wondered if all I could say from the correlations above is that $X_2$ is not the only variable that is correlated with $X_1$. If these interpretations are not correct, what is an appropriate conclusion?

Sorry for posting a 'please check my work' or 'please correct me' question, but I haven't been able to find clear answers.

Comment: It looks like you are looking for a different modeling strategy, and not binary correlations. Maybe what you are looking for is path analysis, have you checked it?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you *controlled* $X_2$ in the experiment?